# How i find a max in a singley linked list internally

Tags: java

code of the `linked list`

```
  class Link 
{
    public Object data;
    public Link next;

    public Link(Object o)
    {
        this.data = o;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return data.toString();
    }
}

class LinkList {
    private Link head;

    public LinkList()
    {
        head = null;
    }
```

the method i created

```
public Object max(){
           Link current=head;
            Comparable max=(Comparable)(head.data);
            while(current!=null){
                if(max.compareTo(current.data)==-1){
                    max=(Comparable)current.data;

                }
                current=current.next;

            }
            return max;

        }
```

the problem is it keep posting this error 
exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to Comparable

i know u will be getting max in case of numbers usually so u can cast it into int  however I'm trying to get the method to work using Comparable 
any ideas??

Comment: Can you post the logic you are using to add to the list too? The above code is working correctly on my system.

Answer (score 1):

you can change your Link class property data type to other Class which implemetns Comparable interface. like my code, and override compareTo method:

```
class Link {
    public MyBean data;
    public Link next;

    public Link(MyBean o) {
        this.data = o;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }
}

class MyBean implements Comparable<MyBean>{
    String name;
    // ... other properties


    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyBean o) {

        return System.identityHashCode(this.name) - System.identityHashCode(o);
    }
}
```